# How to group data into given number of sets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame that stores stocks data(Time, Open, High,... ,Volume,etc). How can I group the data into given number of sets(like 5 or 10), where each set of the data has similar sum of volumes.

I was trying to use 'cumsum' and 'Groupby' function, but it seems like 'Groupby' function cannot make it happen.

Comment: Try posting your code.

Comment: Examples of use cases are always helpful (: